# Margin-right browser

Tags: css

Thanks to everyone, I am Italian, sorry for my English, I would like a clarification:

Why do not all browsers see `margin-right`, while developer tools have `margin-right`? (Firefox does not show `margin-bottom`, in addition to `margin-right`).

**CSS**

```
html
{
background-color:gold;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 6px;
border: solid black 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

In the box model I have the `margin-right`, in the browser it is not considered.

Chrome browser and developer tools box-model:

[image: Chrome browser and developer tools box-model]

Comment: the screenshot is not showing everything

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you make a mocked up screenshot of how you expect it to look vs how it actually looks?

Comment: I agree with @Mr Lister, the question is unclear. If your element is already 100% of the viewport and you have margins, the total box will be 100% + compounded margins. Therefore, the right side of your element will extend beyond the viewport. In your example, the total box width will be 100% + 70px. Not quite sure this is the question though.

Comment: If you set width: 100% of the html tag, then the width of the html box without edges, paddings, and margins is the same as the width of the browser window.
if I set border-left: 100px; border-right: 100px; padding-left: 200px, then the total width of the html box is 100px + 100px + 200px + browser window width, so you would activate the horizontal scroll bar and see borders and padding.
If you also set the right margin of 100px, then the right margin is not properly displayed.
I wanted to know why it does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Your box is [over-constrained](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth)

CSS 2.2 says:

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
>
> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the
>   values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values
>   will have to be different from its computed value. If the 'direction'
>   property of the containing block has the value 'ltr', the specified
>   value of 'margin-right' is ignored and the value is calculated so as
>   to make the equality true. If the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this
>   happens to 'margin-left' instead.

From that, you can see that browsers automatically adjust the right margin, overriding the setting you give it.

Comment: thanks, I finally understood. You have been very precise.

Answer (score 0):

You should take off the width from your css. since you are using margin, you are already telling the browser to only show a space of what you have allowed. It does not affect the height cos the height is pretty much infinite.

So you should have something like this

```
html
{
background-color:gold;
height: 100%;
padding: 6px;
border: solid black 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not always handle all css properties on the html element consistently because it has no parent. If I'm understanding what you want correctly, I'd recommend this if you want to avoid a wrapper div, but it might be a bit unstable:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
    background-color:gold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

See this [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oemRed)

Alternately you can use a wrapper div and avoid doing anything to the HTML tag other than normalizing it (this is what I would recommend):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <!-- All your content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color:gold;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
}

div.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

As [shown here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Evrzwv)

Comment: To be strictly technical, there is nothing special about the HTML element to cause this, but rather it concerns adding styling to elements without a parent. Margin is the most notable one, but any CSS property that references a parent element can go wonky because there is often nothing in the spec to define how the situation should be handled, leaving it up to the developer's discression. This is why margin-left and margin-right usually won't work well, bottom margin is hit and miss, and top margins really only work consistently because of the margin collapse rule.

Comment: @MrLister Reading back on it, that statement does sound a lot more opinionated and forceful than intended, I've edited the answer to hopefully be more clear.